# Can a Cyclone's "Dual Covering Fire" Special Action be used if the Cyclone is engaged in melee?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

This question came up last night while we were playing a game of Warmachine.  A friend was running a Cyclone, and he noticed that the Dual Covering Fire special action is an *Action, not an *Attack.

Does this mean that it can be used even if the Cyclone is engaged?  The Action is attached to the ranged weapon however, so does this make it the equivalent of an *Attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, found this little tidbit here:

http://privateerpressforums.com/showthread.php?12489-Covering-Fire-while-engaged&highlight=dual+covering+fire+melee

It seems that, yes, they can, for the reasons I stated above - because it is a special action, not a special attack.